# On variations of Rowland's sequence using the radical of an integer $\prod_{p\mid n}p$

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, recurrence-relations, prime-factorization, experimental-mathematics

This afternoon I tried to create a Rowland's sequence using the radical of an integer in my formula. I don't know if it was in the literature, but I know that also there were variations on Rowland's recursion in the literature.

**Definition.** I define the sequence with $a_1=1$, and for integers $k\geq 2$ as $$a_k=a_{k-1}+\operatorname{rad}(k+a_{k-1}),\tag{1}$$ where $\operatorname{rad}(n)$ is the radical of the integer $n$, see its definition from this [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radical_of_an_integer).

I've calculated the first terms ($a_k$, with $2\leq k\leq 10$) as $4, 11, 26, 57, 78, 163, 220, 449, 500$.

**Computational fact.** Thus for $2\leq k\leq 10$, I've observed that the absolute value of the differences $a_k-a_{k-1}$ is always a squarefree integer.

I would like to know when fails this conjecture and, if it is possible to set a new conjecture using a new definition.

> **Question.**
>
> A) If you know that this definition was in the literature, please refer it. Find the first $K$ such that there exists a prime $p$ with $p^2$ dividing  $|a_{K}-a_{K-1}|$ (that is, $|a_{K}-a_{K-1}|$ isn't a squarefree integer).
>
> B) Can you set an improvement of my idea definining a Rowland's sequence using the radical of an integer $\operatorname{rad}(n)$ with different $a_1$ and/or with a different formula $(1)$? Thus I am asking to you for a different definition, always using the arithmetic function $\operatorname{rad}(n)$, that provide us a nice statemement or a conjecture for $$|a_{k}-a_{k-1}|\in\text{ a sequence of positive integers},$$ for $k\geq 2$. **Thanks in advance.**

Comment: With $\text{ a sequence of positive integers }$, I want to say a nice sequence (a well-known sequence of positive integers), it is possible include a constant like as the $1$ in the original Rowland's sequence. Many thanks all users.

Comment: If you want to play with weird sequences then you need to compute the first $10^5$ terms and plot them. What mathematical software do you have ? pari/gp is free and works well with very large integers and repeated factorization.

Comment: All users the reference for Rowland's recurrence is Eric S. Rowland, *A Natural Prime-Generating Recurrence*, Journal of Integer Sequences, Volume 11, Issue 2, Article 08.2.8 (2008). It is a free access journal.

Comment: Many thanks for your intention @reuns the problem is that I am a bad programmer. I've pari/gp and and example (yours) but now I don't know how do a call of a routine, where save such routine, how run the routine...

Comment: I type the code in notepad++ then I copy/paste in the console of pari. If you don't like it, download mathematica or anything you want. Search for pari and gp code examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this should answer most of your question:

By definition, $a_k-a_{k-1} = \mathrm{rad}(k+a_{k-1})$. Since $\mathrm{rad}(n)$ is a product of distinct primes for all $n$, it is necessarily squarefree.

Comment: This ends the mystery, many thanks.

Comment: @user243301 You're welcome!

Comment: Since my question was obvious and has no a good matheatical meaning  I've decided select your answer for this post. But If you want to think variations of my idea (not so obvious of mine of course), feel free to do it

Answer (score 0):

Pari/gp code

```
    radical(x)=F=factor(x)[,1];prod(i=1,length(F),F[i]);
    a(k) = if(k > 1, a(k-1)+radical(k+a(k-1)), 1);
    a(10);
    N = 20; t = vector(N); kk = vector(N);
    for (k = 1,N, {t[k] = a(k); kk[k] = k;});
    plothraw(kk,t);
```

Comment: Many thanks, but my succession is obvious.